# DisposableCompletableObserver leaking Activity even though I'm clearing CompositeDisposable

Tags: android, rx-java2, leakcanary

I'm new to RxJava and LeakCanary so this might be something simple (hopefully).

Essentially I have an Activity which includes a `CompositeDisposable`. I get the instance of my Singleton repository and use it to get a `Completable` that is added to the `CompositeDisposable`.

In onPause I clear the `CompositeDisposable` which I'm led to believe will avoid any memory leaks of the calling object (in this case an Activity).

Unfortunately after installing LeakCanary it reports that this Activity is leaked in the repository via the `Completable`.

What am I doing wrong? When Googling it, I don't see anything extra that people are doing.

---

**Note**:

Normally I get an observable from my repository via an `AndroidViewModel`, however in this case I'm using my Settings Activity which has a requirement to make one call to the repository. It doesn't require a ViewModel.

Anyway, because of this LeakCanary was able to notice the Activity was leaked. If I'm not mistaken by default it wouldn't be able to do this on my ViewModels unless I told it to.

So perhaps everything else is being leaked as well but I'm just not aware of it. Ok I just watched one of my AndroidViewModel's and sure enough it's being leaked also (according to LeakCanary). It seems either I'm doing something wrong or LeakCanary is showing a false positive.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

---

Code as requested (**updated**):

```
private CompositeDisposable mSubscriptions;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  mSubscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();
  ...
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSubscriptions.clear();
}

public void someMethodForButtonClick(View view) {
  IwcRepository iwcRepository = 
    Injection.provideIwcRepository(getApplication());
  mSubscriptions.add(iwcRepository.getSomeCompletable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }
            }));
}
```

LeakCanary Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @akarnokd done.

Comment: @akarnokd any ideas?

Comment: When you take the leak canary snapshot, does it call GC to cleanup unreachable references? Was the app paused before the snapshot was taken?

Comment: Also try `onTerminateDetach` before `subscribeWith` to rule out your source keeping references to its subscribers.

Comment: @akarnokd I don't take the snapshot it just happens automatically when there's a leak detected. It shows up as a notification. I don't know if it does a GC call. The app itself is not paused that I know of (but it does seem to pause for a moment when leakCanary flashes on the screen for a moment). Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: I cannot see a way to use onTerminateDetach. Google search has no examples that I can find. It's not recognised code in the IDE.

Comment: Your IDE can't find [this])http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#onTerminateDetach--)? Also as you said, the app is not paused and you only clear the composite when the app pauses...

Comment: @akarnokd no because it's a completable not an observable (I guess that's another quirk of completables - but there's probably a good reason for it). When you said app pause I thought you meant does it literally pause (as in jank type pause). From a code perspective the activity is totally destroyed so yes onPause it definitely called. The debugger confirms mSubscriptions.clear(); is called.

Comment: What is `IwcRepository.sSubscriptions`? It's listed as static. Maybe that IwcRepository stores incoming subscribers that way?

Comment: @akarnokd it's another CompositeDisposable. Should they never be static? Could that be the problem?

Comment: If you don't clear it, then most likely that's the cause of your leak.

Comment: @akarnokd ok I think I have a way of removing the CompositeDisposable completely from that class (since I wrote that I've learned a few more rxjava tricks). I have to go now but I'll update later today if it worked or not. thanks for the tip!

Comment: actually I can't work on it today but I'll update when I do.

Comment: @akarnokd ok I've removed the CompositeDisposable from the repository and the memory leak is now gone! You were right in that it was the source of the leak. If you want to answer the question I'll mark it as correct. Otherwise I will just answer myself. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You can answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as mentioned in the comments I resolved this error by removing the CompositeDisposable from the repository. New to RxJava I didn't know how to use it properly. I had subscriptions inside subscriptions rather than chaining and returning one observable, and subscribing once at the end of the chain. I.e. my repository didn't actually need to subscribe to anything, it just needed to tack on some logic or do some "andThen's".